# Consuming C++ 20 modules library exports from a CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I have a very simple CMake project using experimental C++ 20 modules to create a library. The library exports a class.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS YES)

project(TestLib CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.27.0")
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
else()
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "aa1f7df0-828a-4fcd-9afc-2dc80491aca7")
endif()

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES YES)

set(TESTLIB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

add_library(TestLib)
target_sources(TestLib PUBLIC FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    "${TESTLIB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/module.ixx"
)
```

The question is: how do I consume the class exported by the module in the compiled library from another CMake project (not nested in a subfolder)?